# How to use a variable again in a new function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm using this function to insert html in elements (.catch), and I need this to be executed only when the touch event is caught on a new element, different than the previous one.

First I'm catching the touch position, next I want to check if the *new id* is different from the *previous id* with `id != lastid`. But this doesn't work, *lastid* is *undefined*. How can I re-use the value of `var lastid` when the touch event is caught on new element ?

```
var lastid ; 
$('.catch').bind('touchmove', function (evt) {
    var touch = evt.originalEvent.touches[0];
    var element = $(document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY));
    var id = document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY).id;
    if ( element.hasClass('catch') && id != lastid){    
        //Changing the value 
        lastid = id ;
        // execute the rest of the function here 
        // ....
        // ....
        return lastid;
    }
});
```

Thank you !

edit : <strike>var lastid = id ;</strike>

Comment: Here's an article on scope in JavaScript: https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Comment: So, if _lastid_ is local, how can I check if this is a new id ? any way to make it global to reuse outside the function ? or should it be done an other way ?

Comment: Allright, other comments and the link helped me to find the different issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `var` inside the function. Just use `lastid = id`, specifying `var` declares it <s>again</s> **another variable with the same name** inside the closure (i.e. function) shadowing the `lastid` declared outside the function and making it inaccessible when inside the function (you have no way of accessing both values)

```
        //Changing the value 
        lastid = id ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but even with your modification, it's still undefined on the next call to the function.

Comment: Are you sure your other variables have valid values, like `element` and `id`? Are you sure the code is going into your `if` statement where `lastid` gets assigned?

Comment: Yes they were, it was in the rest of the code, after `if` I had `else` condition, that was changing the scope of the variable _lastid_ again. Thanks all for pointing this mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript variables have function scope.

```
if ( element.hasClass('catch') && id != lastid)
    {   
        //Changing the value 
        var lastid = id ;
        // execute the rest of the function here 
        // ....
        // ....
        return lastid;
    }
```

This would create a new local variable lastid and the desired variable will not be updated. Remove 'var' to assign value to  variable, 'lastid' declared outside the function's local scope.

```
    if ( element.hasClass('catch') && id != lastid)
    {   
        //Changing the value 
        lastid = id ;
        // execute the rest of the function here 
        // ....
        // ....
        return lastid;
    }
```

To deal with the undefined status of lastid, initialise it with some legal value.